# binomial random variable concentration property

Tags: probability

Consider a simple game with a coin with head probability $p$. The rule is---toss the coin $n$ times.

Whenever we observe tail, multiply by $c_1$.
Whenever observe head, multiply by $c_2$.

So the equation is $z := c_1^{n-X_n} c_2^{X_n}$ where $X_n$ is the binomial distribution.

Here is the question: for given $c_1, c_2 > 0$, does $z$ converge to $0$ or $\infty$ with probability $1$? I mean the limiting value is a *deterministic* function of $c_1, c_2$ when $n \to \infty$.

I think concentration property of binomial helps, but it has $n$ term and $X_n$ term both, not trivial to me. Any thought?

Comment: Presumably the crossover point is when $R:=c_1^{q} c_2^{p}=1$, since the "typical" value of $z$ is $R^n$. If $R<1$ then it seems straightforward to show $z \to 0$ in distribution, if $R>1$ then it seems straightforward to show $z \to \infty$ in distribution. Getting a.s. convergence might take a little more effort.

Comment: Thanks Ian, yes intuitively I agree. But how can I formally show it? I am not a math person :(....in distribution convergence is okay.

Comment: How exactly do you get new values of $z$ as $n$ increases? Is $z_{101}$ just $z_{100}$ times either $c_1$ or $c_2$ (depending on the $101$st toss) or do you toss the coin $101$ times to get a completely independent result?

Comment: sorry for confusion! $z_{101} = c_1 z_{100}$ or $c_2 z_{100}$. (But does it make a difference?)

Answer (score 1):

Let $q=1-p,R=c_1^q c_2^p$.

Let $\Delta_n=X_n-np$. Then $z=R^n \left ( \frac{c_2}{c_1} \right )^{\Delta_n} = \left ( R \left ( \frac{c_2}{c_1} \right )^{\frac{\Delta_n}{n}} \right )^n$.

Now you might want to just say $\Delta_n/n \to 0$ almost surely and say that then $z$ behaves like $R^n$, but that is not entirely safe due to the growing exponent on the outside. (This kind of reasoning can lead to errors such as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n=1$.)

Instead notice that what you need for $z$ to go to zero almost surely is that eventually $\left ( \frac{c_2}{c_1} \right )^{\Delta_n/n} < 1/R$. If $R<1$ then after some routine algebra, this becomes either $\frac{\Delta_n}{n} < c$ for some $c>0$ or $\frac{\Delta_n}{n}>c$ for some $c<0$, depending on the relative sizes of $c_1,c_2$. Similarly, what you need for $z$ to go to $\infty$ almost surely is that eventually $\left ( \frac{c_2}{c_1} \right )^{\Delta_n/n} >1/R$ which reduces to the same conditions on $\Delta_n$ provided $R>1$.

Thus, if $R<1$ or $R>1$ then $z$ behaves in the limit like $R^n$, going to zero in the first case and $\infty$ in the second case. If $R=1$ then you will expect wild fluctuations as $n \to \infty$.

The general "limit algebra" trick you can extract from here is that if $X_n \to x$ almost surely, $x \neq 0$, and $a_n \to \infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n X_n) = \lim_{y \to \operatorname{sign}(x) \infty} f( y)$ almost surely (provided the RHS exists). What you *cannot* do is push this to the case $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I think your "limit algebra" trick is the key, which solves my point. Is there any reference for it?

Comment: @Jayboy I don't really have a reference, it's just doing the same thing I did in this specific case: if $x>0$, let $0<\epsilon<x$, conclude that almost surely $X_n>x-\epsilon$ eventually and analogous if $x<0$. Then apply the definition of the limit at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Write $A_n=X_n/n$, so that $A_n$ converges almost surely to $p$  by the law of large numbers. Also,
$$z =\exp(n(\ln(c_1)-A_n\ln(c_1)+ A_n\ln(c_2))= \exp(n U_n).$$
As $U_n$ converges a.s. to $u=\ln(c_1)+p\ln(c_2/c_1)$, $z$ converges to $+\infty$ if $u>0$ and to $0$ if $u<0$.

Comment: oh wait Vincent, as the exponential term has $n$ and $U_n$ both, I don't think this convergence proof works

Comment: @Jayboy It basically works, though there is a minor error (the cutoff is at $u=0$). The point is basically that $U_n$ converges a.s. to something nonzero and $n \to \infty$ so you just pass the a.s. limit inside $\exp$, and then there's no indeterminate form in there.

Comment: Thank you, the threshold value is indeed 0...